# Problem creating a directory with a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to use a batch script to create a folder and a subfolder with dates.

What I want is to create a folder in the directory as `November 2018` and inside it another folder called `27-11-2018`.

What I have tried so far is:

```
@echo off
set day=%Date:~0,2%
set month=%Date:~3,2%
set year=%Date:~6,4%

echo %day%
echo %month%
echo %year%

if %month%==11 set month-name=November

pause

set folder="%month-name% %year%\%day%-%month%-%year%"
echo %folder%
md %folder%

pause
```

The output is:

```
27
11
2018
Press any key to continue . . .
"November 2018\27-11-2018"
The system cannot find the path specified.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The echoed line is correct and the `November 2018` folder is created, but not the subfolder.

What I've tried is to create just `November 2018` folder and this works, but obviously, this, doesn't create subfolder.

I've also replaced the space with underscore as per below and this works, too so it seems like its the space causing the issue.

```
set folder="%month-name%_%year%\%day%-%month%-%year%"
```

Any ideas? I am sure there has got to be an easy answer to this.

Comment: For mkdir to create nested folders in one go you need extensions to be enabled (should be default), otherwise use `setlocal EnableExtensions`.

Comment: @LotPings, if the command extensions were disabled, the message would be `The directory or file cannot be created.`...

Answer (score 1):

For mkdir to create nested folders in one go you need extensions to be enabled (should be default), otherwise use `setlocal EnableExtensions`.

I suggest not to use the %date% variable which is locale/user settings dependent.
Use either wmic or PowerShell for this.

Also create a MonthName array and use the month as an index to select current month.

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\11\27\SO_53497757.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion


:: Build MonthName[01..12] array
Set i=100&Set "MonthName= January February March April May June July August September October November December"
Set "MonthName=%MonthName: ="&Set /a i+=1&Set "MonthName[!i:~-2!]=%"
:: Set MonthName

:: get datetime independent of locale/user settings.
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=.+-" %%A in (
  'wmic os get LocalDateTime^|findstr ^^[0-9]'
) do Set _IsoDT=%%A
Set "yy=%_IsoDT:~0,4%"&Set "MM=%_IsoDT:~4,2%"&Set "dd=%_IsoDT:~6,2%"

set "folder=!MonthName[%MM%]! %yy%\%dd%-%MM%-%yy%"

echo %folder%
md "%folder%"
```

**EDIT: alternatively use a PowerShell one liner wrapped in batch**

```
powershell -NoP -C "md (get-date).ToString('MMMM yyyy\\dd-MM-yyyy')"
```

Comment: Is there anything specific that Need to be enabled for this to run correctly etc? I've ran the code attached and I still get the same issue..?

Comment: As the batch explicitly enables extensions it should run as is, I tested it here successfully. What exact windows version are you using? See  edit answer with an alternativ powershell one liner.

Comment: Windows 7 Enterprise SP1

Comment: Has the drive, you are running this in, other restrictions (rights probaply)? Does it work on a local drive?

Comment: its a network drive so there might be but I haven't got admin rights to change these

Comment: @DrunkenAntic, what happens if you try to create the folders manually in Windows Explorer, with the same user account that is executing your batch file?

Comment: I've run the script on a local drive and it works fine so it does seem to be an issue one the network drives.

Comment: ATM I've no clue, I use a similar batch and script to generate the daily structure as in the file name `Q:\Test\2018\11\27\SO_53497757.cmd` on my NAS without problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do not create both dir and subdir in one go. First create dir then create subdir in it.

```
set folder="%month-name% %year%"
echo %folder%
md %folder%
cd %folder%
set folder="%day%-%month%-%year%"
echo %folder%
md %folder%
```

Comment: Are u able to do cd %folder% ?

Comment: Yes, I've also echoed %cd% and it shows November 2018 folder

Comment: Why should one not make use of the nice `mkdir` feature of creating the whole tree in one shot??

Comment: Because the end result is still the same